# Laravel Eloquent: merge model with Input

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to know how it is possible to merge data from `Input::all()` with a model and save the result.

To clarify: I would like to do something like below:

```
$product = Product::find(1); // Eloquent Model

$product->merge( Input::all() ); // This is what I am looking for :)

$product->save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `update` method:

```
$product->update(Input::all());
```

But I recommend to use `only` method instead

```
$product->update(Input::only('name', 'type...'));
```

Comment: Thank you! Just tried it out but passing the data to save() does (unfortunately) not save anything :/ Did you try this?

Comment: If you instantiate a new model: `$product = new Product;` you can use the `save` method.

Comment: You can use `all()` method when you declare `protected $fillable = ['field_1', 'field_n'];` in your model. Then only these columns are being mass-assigned and no additional fields an attacker may have added. See @cy-rossignol answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the model's `fill()` method for greater control. This lets us change attributes after merging the values *before* we save:

```
$product->fill($request->all());
$product->foo = 'bar';
$product->save();
```

If we've [properly defined](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) the model's `$fillable` attributes, there's no need to use `Input::only(...)` (or `$request->only(...)` in newer versions).

Comment: Do I have to take care of `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at` ? Laravel 5.6 is used here.

Comment: @Roland, as long as we don't declare those attributes in `$fillable`, we don't need to filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Razor's answer, if you need to create a new model you can use:

```
$product = Product::create(Input::all());
```

Comment: This allows adding more fields being updated on each invocation of `update()` method (controller).

Comment: But: **Any** data from `Input` class is being taken.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way now is to use FormRequest and the validated function like this :

```
public function update(Product $product, ProductFormRequest $request)        
    {
        $product->update($request->validated());
        //...
    }
```